# Одинаковое свойство у объектов

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

В админке могу редактировать новость (титулка, аннотация, осн. текст), это все на 3-х языках. Хочу сделать так, что если какое-то поле не изменялось, то мы его не сохраняли (т.к. будет 9 полей, по 3 на каждый язык).

Создаю прототип для новости:

```
var proto_content =
{
    title:"",
    annon:"",
    text:"",
    len:new Array(6)
};
```

потом объекты:

```
var content_rus = Object.Create(proto_content);
var content_eng = Object.Create(proto_content);
var content_fra = Object.Create(proto_content);
```

при заполнении:

```
content_rus.len[0] = 1;
content_eng.len[0] = 2;
content_fra.len[0] = 3;
```

при выводе:

```
content_rus.len[0] -> 3
content_eng.len[0] -> 3
content_fra.len[0] -> 3
```

Почему свойство одно на все объекты?
*Пробовал new **Object(proto_content)**.... та же история.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив в данном случае передаётся по ссылке:

```
[] == []; // false (разные инстансы)
content_rus.len == content_eng.len; // true (инстанс один и тот же)
```

Лично я бы в данном случае заюзал функцию конструктор:

```
var Content = function Content () {
    this.title = '';
    this.annon = '';
    this.text = '';
    this.len = new Array(6);
};

var content_rus = new Content();
```

Comment: Проблему я нашёл в другом, но буду пользоваться этим способом создания прототипа.